# Is the Timeout directive of Apache overrideable in htaccess or inside of a <VirtualHost>?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, timeout, virtualhost

I want to override the Timeout configuration of apache, only for one domain. I would prefer to be able to offer the option of overriding it in the htaccess, but manually configuring it in the VirtualHost configuration would be fine too.

Is this supposed to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

TimeOut Directive

Description: Amount of time the server will wait for certain events before failing a request
Syntax: TimeOut seconds
Default: TimeOut 300
Context: server config, **virtual host**
Status: Core
Module: core